# sql json extract scalar with different keys in json

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

have a 'dateinfo' column that I extract from a table in Athena, which is a json like the ones you can see below.

```
[{"pickuprequesteddate":"2022-08-09T00:00:00"}, {"deliveryrequesteddate":"2022-08-09T00:00:00"}]

[{"departureestimateddate":"2022-08-25T00:00:00"}, {"arrivalestimateddate":"2022-10-07T00:00:00"}, {}, {}]
```

As you can see inside the json there are different keys. I am interested in extracting the values for 'pickuprequesteddate' and 'deliveryrequesteddate' if they are in the json array. That is, for the examples above I would like to obtain as a result a column with the following values:

```
[2022-08-09T00:00:00,deliveryrequesteddate":"2022-08-09T00:00:00]
[null, null, null, null]
```

I know how to extract the values of each key but separately, using

```
TRANSFORM(CAST(stopinfo AS ARRAY<JSON>), x -> JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.dateinfo.pickuprequesteddate')) as pickup,
    TRANSFORM(CAST(stopinfo AS ARRAY<JSON>), x -> JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.dateinfo.deliveryrequesteddate')) as delivery
```

However, this gives me two separate columns.

How could I extract the values the way I want?

Comment: I've noticed a lot of questions about AWS Athena are co-tagged 'mysql'. Is there some myth among Athena users that Athena SQL syntax is compatible with MySQL SQL syntax? From what I've seen of Athena, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one is present in the object you can use `coalesce`:

```sql
WITH dataset (stopinfo) AS (
   VALUES (JSON '[{"pickuprequesteddate":"2022-08-09T00:00:00"}, {"deliveryrequesteddate":"2022-08-09T00:00:00"}]'),
   (JSON '[{"departureestimateddate":"2022-08-25T00:00:00"}, {"arrivalestimateddate":"2022-10-07T00:00:00"}, {}, {}]')
)

-- query
select TRANSFORM(
        CAST(stopinfo AS ARRAY(JSON)),
        x-> coalesce(
            JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.pickuprequesteddate'),
            JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.deliveryrequesteddate')
        )
    )
from dataset;
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [2022-08-09T00:00:00, 2022-08-09T00:00:00] |
| [NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL] |